# Update parent label from within a view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to update a label on a parent view, but I don't seem to be able to figure it out. My app is a Master/Detail type app. Within the Detail view, I have a UIScrollView, with 5 or so new view controllers inside, each displaying an image.

When an image is touched, I want the label on the Detail view to be updated. In my custom View Controller.h I have the following:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UltimateRageAppDelegate.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

    DetailViewController *vc;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController *vc;

@end
```

And in my View Controller.m file I have:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize vc, imageShow, imageName;

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

vc.clipboardLabel.text  = @"DID THIS WORK?";
NSLog(@"touches ended");

}

@end
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work. I've declared and synthesised an IBOutlet clipboardLabel in my DetailViewController, and I can update the label from within DetailViewController no problems.

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@", vc);` print in the `touchesEnded:withEvent:` method?

Comment: Good question - it prints (null) there's my problem! I don't see where the problem is though, am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've not set your `vc` property properly. You should set it when you are creating your `MyViewController` instance.

```
MyViewController * viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
viewController.vc = self;
[..]
```

This is assuming that you are in `DetailViewController`.

Comment: PERFECT. Worked as expected. Thank you so much.

Comment: The only problem now is MyViewController's dealloc method no longer gets called when I go back to the master view.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is that `@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController *vc;` should be `@property (nonatomic, assign) DetailViewController *vc;`. You should be storing a weak reference to the parent view controller.

Comment: If I use assign I then get an error on my synthesize: Existing ivar 'vc' for unsafe_unretained property 'vc' must be __unsafe_unretained

Comment: As above. Had to edit the comment as it sent before I had finished.

Comment: Just to be sure, has the NDA been lifted?

Comment: I don't think it'll be lifted until GM release.

Comment: I can't discuss it as it is under NDA. Sorry.

Comment: Ok. I think I'll try and go back to the old Xcode. Thanks for all your help Deepak! Have a nice day.